# making certain question types more searchable

Tags: discussion, titles

Suppose someone wants help evaluating a complicated integral. Short of cramming the entire integral into the title, I'm not sure how a person can descriptively choose a title for the question. That is leading to such well thought-out question titles such as "integral help!!!" or "tricky integral problem."

It would be really nice to have less stupid titles. I couldn't find a guideline along these lines ("post the integral in the title") but I wonder if we can't make it a guideline.

Are there any good reasons against this practice? (Aside from maybe weird rendering issues?)

Comment: See: [More informative titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785/more-informative-titles). There is also a [comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4931/).

Comment: You can lead users to a guideline, but you can't make them read/follow it. Presumably, someone already gave them a guideline such as "do your homework", and you can see how that worked out.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the relevant links... I hope either here or there it can finally be decided if this practice is good or bad.

Comment: @5pm I guess I am just looking for approval for the idea of "when in doubt, make it the title."

Comment: I have taken questions with uninformative titles and edited the title to something like, "Integral involving the log of the sine" or "Integral involving trig functions and exponentials." When it's possible to make this kind of edit, I think it improves searchability.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah that is good advice. I think rather than "when in doubt" I'd like to revise it to "when all else fails."